# How do I detect if an optional keyword was supplied to a declarative macro?

Tags: rust, macros, rust-decl-macros

I'm writing a macro:

```
macro_rules! foo {
    ($(print)?) => {
        // run `println!("hello") if print is given
    }
}
```

Which could be called as:

- `foo!()` which would do nothing
- `foo!(print)` which would print hello

How do I detect if `print` was supplied? When I use a repetition operator I need to put a variable in. Is there some sort of empty variable I can use? (`(print $print:empty)?`)

Comment: As mentioned in the duplicate — define two patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Make separate rules for each case:

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    () => {
        // do nothing
    };
    (print) => {
        println!("hello")
    };
}

fn main() {
    foo!(); // does nothing
    foo!(print); // prints "hello"
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b7d636220f480d25eddee850a62a9f78)

Comment: Please search for and suggest duplicates before answering.